# Opening images one after the other

Tags: c++, image, opencv, video

I have a series of images saved on my system according to their time stamps.

For example the images are named as:

`20140305180348.jpg`

`20140305180349.jpg`

I have 100 such images, I want to open them using OpenCV one after the other. I have tried using `cvCapturefromFile()` but using it I am able to open just a single image at a time. I want to stitch/join them so that I can make a video.

I am sorry I cannot post the code as I am not allowed to. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenCV, to write images to a video, you can use [`VideoWriter`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter) (and do it in a loop to read a sequence of images):

```
VideoWriter outputVideo; // Open the output

// ... set video properties like FPS

if (!outputVideo.isOpened())
{
    cout  << "Could not open the output video for write: " << source << endl;
    return -1;
}

for(...)
{
   // read your frame, e.g. to Mat img

   // outputVideo.write(img); //save or
   outputVideo << img;
}

cout << "Finished writing" << endl;
```

Check out [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html) is an example how to write a video. Just modify the `for`-loop in the end.

pseudocode:

```
open videocontainer
int i=0;
while(i<100){
    Mat img = imread("path"+to_string(i)+".jpg");
    outputvideo << img;
}
close videocontainer
```